# Where or how do I register a new phone number intended to be used with voip?

Tags: voip

Ok I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask.

Goal:
Have a voicemailbox with multiple phone numbers. 1 in each continent.
Example:
+1123456 -> voicemailbox
+49123456 -> voicemailbox

The scope of the question is,
where do I register a new phone number?
In the US, Sweden, Germany

I live in Germany. There are multiple free phone number providers.
My question is where do they get their phone numbers from?
What do they have to do in order to register a new number?

When I sign up with them I use their hard and software but I'd like to build my own solution.

Let's say I'd like to provide such a service and be able to provide free phone numbers, who do I talk to, where do I go?

Comment: You simply talk with a ITSP who can provision DIDs for you. You can also use a service such as DID Xchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each country has it's own top level "regulator" that is responsible for telphone number management.

In Germany it is the [Bun­desnet­za­gen­tur](http://www.bundesnetzagentur.de/cln_1422/EN/Areas/Telecommunications/Companies/NumberManagement/numbermanagement_node.html)

> is responsible for structuring the national numbering space, setting the conditions for allocating and using numbers, and processing applications for numbers and number blocks.

In the UK it is [Ofcom](http://stakeholders.ofcom.org.uk/telecoms/numbering/)

> This section provides information about UK Telephone Numbers, and allows Communications Providers to apply for Telephone Numbers from the National Numbering Scheme.

In the UK you have to be a communications provider to apply for a number or block of numbers.

As a consumer you are allocated a number by the provider you sign up with.